# How to search for a specific string and replace a number in this string usign python?

Tags: python-3.x, search, replace, str-replace

I have a text file that is a Fortran code. I am trying to create copies (Fortran files) of this code. But in each copy I create I want to find and replace few things. As an example:

This is the code and I want to search for pMax, tShot, and replace the numbers next to it.

I would be grateful if someone can give me a hint on how this can be done using python 3.x. Thank you.

This is my try at it:

There is no error but for some reason, re.sub() doesn't replace the string with the desired string 'pMax' in the destination file. Although printing the return value of re.sub shows that the pMax is modified to the desired value.

```
vd_load_name = []
for i in range(len(Pressure_values)):
    vd_load_name.append('{}_{}MPa'.format(n,int(Pressure_values[i])))   

src_dir = os.getcwd() #get the current working dir


# create a dir where we want to copy and rename
dest_dir = os.mkdir('vd_loads')
os.listdir()

dest_dir = src_dir+"/vd_loads"

for i in range(len(vd_load_name)):
    src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, 'n_t05_pressure_MPa.txt')
    shutil.copy(src_file,dest_dir) #copy the file to destination dir

    dst_file = os.path.join(dest_dir,'n_t05_pressure_MPa.txt')
    new_dst_file_name = os.path.join(dest_dir, vd_load_name[i]+'.txt')

    os.rename(dst_file, new_dst_file_name)#rename
    os.chdir(dest_dir)

dest_file_path = dest_dir+'/'+vd_load_name[i]+'.txt'
with open(dest_file_path,'r+') as reader:
    #reading all the lines in the file one by one
    for line in reader:
       re.sub(r"pMax=\d+", "pMax=" + str(int(Pressure_values[i])), line)         
       print(re.sub(r"pMax=\d+", "pMax=" + str(int(Pressure_values[i])), line))
```

Actualy part of the fortran code that I want to edit:

```
 integer :: i               !shot index in x
 integer :: j               !shot index in y
 integer :: sigma           !1D overlap

     dimension curCoords(nblock,ndim), velocity(nblock,ndim),dirCos(nblock,ndim,ndim), value(nblock)
     character*80 sname

 pMax=3900d0                !pressure maximum [MPa]    Needs to be updated!!
 fact=1d0                   !correction factor

 JLTYP=0                    !key that identifies the distributed load type, 0 for Surface-based load

 t=stepTime                 !current time[s]
 tShot=1.2d-7               !Time of a shot[s]           Needs to be updated!!
 sigma=0            !1D overlap in x&y [%]
```

Comment: This regex doesn't feel right. I think you should use `r"pMax=\d+"`. `\d` is regex class for digits, + means at least one occurrence and r denotes raw string in Python which should be used when dealing with regular expressions. 
In the end it would be something like `re.sub(r"pMax=\d+", "pMax=" + str(int(Pressure_values[i])), line)`.

Comment: The code earlier works for finding the right line: it gives an output:Match Found <re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='\t pMax=3900d0\t'>
Match Found <re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='\t tShot=1.2d-7\t'>
Match Found <re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='\t pMax=3900d0\t'>
 The reason for using a strange pattern is that the tabs and spaces are important for the Fortran script. I have modified the  py script as you suggested but it doesn't replace the desired value. Could it be because of the 'r+' mode while opening the file?

Comment: r+ opens file for reading and writing. I don't see any writing to the file in the code you posted so I can't comment on that.
Try to solve one problem at a time. My solution leaves tabs and spaces intact but substitutes the assignment. 
`re.search` is completely unnecessary because you can do search and replace (re. sub). Can you try to replace for loop body with `print(re.sub(r"pMax=\d+", "pMax=" + str(int(Pressure_values[i])), line))`? It will output the file so you see whether the substitution works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it does work when I print it. The values of pMax are changing as expected. I think there is some problem in writing it to the file. I always checked the written files and there is no change in them. Printing the re.sub showed that it is indeed changing the pMax. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Can you upvote my comment/s?